# Diffraction grating from first principles

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

I have realised that a lot of books and online resources fail to give a detailed treatment of the derivation of the diffraction grating interference pattern. Normally only the result is stated. I was wondering whether there is any special reason for this, is the maths to complicated for a 2nd year undergraduate physic course? I would appreciate it if someone could outline how one could derive the diffraction grating interference pattern using the  Frauenhofer integral and/or convolution theorem?

Thank you

Comment: The derivation of general diffraction (including, but not limited to gratings) is covered by any modern 2nd year course worth its admission fee. Holograms and x-ray diffraction images can be derived with Fourier transform, which should be first year material in a good physics course. Did you look at the online resources? There should be plenty of derivations for the general case.

Comment: @CuriousOne I checked but ,unfortunately I could not find anything useful. A link to a good article would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you I had a look at it and it was really helpful. I just have one more brief question. When you do the Frauenhofer integral which yields a complex amplitude, is the intensity then given by the modulus squared of the waves amplitude (opposed to the (real part of the amplitude) squared)?

Comment: I believe so. Using complex waves shouldn't make any difference, since the real and imaginary terms should always stay orthogonal to each other. There may be exceptions to that rule, like with multiple polarized waves and reflections on triple mirrors that introduce topological phase shifts in three dimensions, but I would have to think about that and I think that case if of no importance here.